# Detect mouse click events while ignoring mouse movements in a windows console

Tags: c, winapi, console, mouse

I have a `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` based loop, that (in addition to other stuff), triggers on keyboard and mouse events.  Firstly setting:

```
SetConsoleMode(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT);
```

And then using:

```
GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
```

As an event added to `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` .

Now this is working fine but I'm really only interested in the mouse position when clicked.  But naturally it is triggering for mouse movement as well.  Is there any way of excluding mouse movement from the event such that `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` will only awaken on mouse click and will ignore mouse movement?

Comment: perhaps add a win32 tag to this? and show your WSA code. and this is really a C question.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I have added the tag.

Comment: `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents()` is intended for waiting on socket events. Why are you using it for console events, too? Unless you are intermixing socket activity and console input on the same thread (which you shouldn't be), you should use `[Msg]WaitForMultipleObjects()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-wsawaitformultipleevents) for `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` states that the current implementation of that function calls `WaitForMultipleObjectsEx`. Therefore, there is no difference between calling these two functions. Although this may theoretically change in a future version of Windows, I consider this highly unlikely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way of excluding mouse movement from the event such that `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` will only awaken on mouse click and will ignore mouse movement?

No.  Using `ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT` means that the console handle satisfies the wait on *any* mouse activity within the console window while the window is focused.  That includes both mouse movements and mouse clicks.  The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode) even says as much.  So, you will just have to receive and discard the console events that you are not interested in.